# The use of "natural" in my sentence

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "It's natural" in my sentence?

> "Why do men flirt?"
> "They are men. It's natural."

Comment: It is not a complete sentence but not ungrammatical. As an argument, it says nothing. Women flirt too, and it is natural because they are women.

Comment: Yes it is a complete sentence. It has a noun "It" and a predicate "is natural".

Comment: Your question would be better if you identified a reason why this is a concern to you.  Why do you think "It's natural" might be ungrammatical or not idiomatic?

Comment: It's natural. is a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is a complete sentence and grammatically correct.  It suggests that "It is natural for men to flirt".

It doesn't answer the question in a very deep way.  It is like saying "Why are elephants grey?" "Because they are elephants. It's natural (for elephants to be grey)" This doesn't actually explain *why*. And there are some rather unpleasant sexist undertones in the answer. (It hints that it is okay for men to sexually harass women)

Comment: "Flirting" is "sexual harassment"? This is the first I heard of such thing.

Comment: Flirting isn't sexual harassment, of course not.   But flirting is often used as a euphemism or disguise of sexual harassment.  "The repeated comments I made about her weren't sexual harassment, I was just 'flirting'."  When I see statements like "It's natural for men to flirt" it suggests that someone is feeling defensive about their flirting.  That suggest what they call "flirting" actually is harassment.